# spoon from kettle does not run in windows

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to run kettle.
I run spoon.bat. It finds the environment variables correctly and launches launcher.jar.
After launcher screen displayed a few seconds it disappears and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide any more details? Are there any error messages printed to the console? We'll need more information in order to help you.

Comment: have you prepared your windows environtment correctly? This article may help you http://pentahogurus.blogspot.com/2012/12/pentaho-data-integration-for-first-time.html

Comment: if you are saying that it finds environment variables correctly then you have to look into the log file and in some case few problems are solved by updating your jdk so try to set jdk 1.7 may be your find what you want.

Comment: have you solved this problem ? I have encountered same.

Comment: I installed another kettle!

Comment: See it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/198337/141352

Answer (score 1):

Add this into Spoon.bat file:

```
"-Duser.region=US" "-Duser.language=en"
```

after:

```
"-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

check the spoon.bat. Make sure whether enough memory is allocated to xmx variable (atleast 512 mb).